# javascript: замена слов в строке из списка

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения, typescript, for, replace

есть строка `text` и массив ключевых слов `this.state.keywords`

необходимо произвести замену ключевых слов `XXX` в строке на выражения вида `<span class = 'c0*'>XXX</span>`

где `*` - значение от 1 до 4 (по сути номер ключевого слова в словаре по модулю 4)

Написал такой код:

```
highlightText = (text: string) => {
    let output: string = text;
    let index: number = 0;
    for (const keyword of this.state.keywords) {
        output = output.replace(new RegExp(keyword, 'ig'), `<span class='c0${index % 4 + 1}'>${keyword}</span>`, );
        index += 1;
    }

    return output;
}
```

Как по мне он корявенький и избыточный.

Подскажите, как бы его сделать поэлегантнее, условно можно ли его схлопнуть в пару строк

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По короче - можно так.

```
const highlightText = (text) => {
    this.state.keywords.forEach((keyword, i) => {
        text = text.replace(new RegExp(keyword, "gi"), `<span class='c0${i % 4 + 1}'>${keyword}</span>`)
    })
    return text;
}
```

Удобнее для чтения - вот так:

```
const highlightText = (text) => {
    const keywords = this.state.keywords;

    keywords.forEach((keyword, i) => {
        const template =  `<span class='c0${i % 4 + 1}'>${keyword}</span>`
        const re = new RegExp(keyword, "gi");

        text = text.replace(re, template)
    })
    return text
}
```

Comment: кстати из ваш код натолкнул на такую идею: `highlightText = (text: string) => this.state.keywords.reduce((res, keyword, i) => res = res.replace(new RegExp(keyword, "gi"), ``<span class = 'c0${i % 4 + 1}'>${keyword}</span>``), text);`